# Why is "height: auto !important;" in the default AMP CSS style sheet? Can it be overridden?

Tags: css, flexbox, amp-html

This CSS code is in the [default AMP style sheet](https://github.com/ampproject/amphtml/blob/master/css/amp.css?TB_iframe=true&width=369.9&height=657.9):

```
html, body {
  height: auto !important;
}
```

It becomes a problem if you want to use flexbox to make sure the body of the HTML document takes up the whole screen, even if there is not enough content to take up the full screen.  For that to work, you need to set the height of `html, body` to `100%`.

[Here is an example](https://philipwalton.github.io/solved-by-flexbox/demos/sticky-footer/) of using flexbox to make sure your footer is at the bottom even when there is not enough content on the page.

Any way to accomplish this and still remain Google AMP compatible?

Comment: You can open an AMPHTML issue tracker [here](https://github.com/ampproject/amphtml/issues) with regard to your situation.

Answer (score -1):

I don't know how to fix your flexbox issue, however, I came to this page looking for a way to get 100% background and managed to figure out how to get the html element to 100% page height. However, because amp sets `position: relative!important;` on the body element, the same trick cannot be used to set body height. So - to end, no, I don't have a solve to your issue. But maybe a start or perhaps will help someone else with the background issue.

```
<html class='max'></html>

.max {
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  position: absolute;
}

html {
  background: #c5975b no-repeat url("<img-URL>");
  background-size: auto 100%;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use `min-height: 100vh;`

```css
body {
    min-height: 100vh;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}
```

full sample code: https://amp-cover-image.glitch.me/

[image]

Answer (score -2):

You can achieve this by setting min-width: 100% to body and html.

Answer (score -2):

The posted question does not have a clear solution. The height auto rule can not be overwritten by using the following example.

```
html, body{
  height: 100% !important;
}
```

I assume the Amp team noticed this and replaced your example:

```
html, body {
  height: auto !important;
}
```

with the following code:

```
html:not([amp4ads]),
html:not([amp4ads]) body{
  height: auto !important;
}
```

After this change it is now possible to overwrite height auto rule by using the same selector:

```
html:not([amp4ads]),
html:not([amp4ads]) body{
  height: 100% !important;
}
```

Comment: Hasn't worked for me. Validation error: "Usage of the !important CSS qualifier is not allowed."